# Python Beautifulsoup Find_all except

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm struggling to find a simple to solve this problem and hope you might be able to help.

I've been using Beautifulsoup's find all and trying some regex to find all the items except the 'emptyLine' line in the html below:

```
<div class="product_item0 ">...</div>
<div class="product_item1 ">...</div>
<div class="product_item2 ">...</div>
<div class="product_item0 ">...</div>
<div class="product_item1 ">...</div>
<div class="product_item2 ">...</div>
<div class="product_item0 ">...</div>
<div class="product_item1 last">...</div>
<div class="product_item2 emptyItem">...</div>
```

Is there a simple way to find all the items except one including the 'emptyItem'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just skip elements containing the `emptyItem` class. Working sample:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<div>
    <div class="product_item0">test0</div>
    <div class="product_item1">test1</div>
    <div class="product_item2">test2</div>
    <div class="product_item2 emptyItem">empty</div>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

for elm in soup.select("div[class^=product_item]"):
    if "emptyItem" in elm["class"]:  # skip elements having emptyItem class
        continue

    print(elm.get_text())
```

Prints:

```
test0
test1
test2
```

Note that the `div[class^=product_item]` is a CSS selector that would match all `div` elements with a class starting with `product_item`.